# warning about ambiguous for ofstream, but not for ostream. What's the difference?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

This is not important. But I'm curious as to when this warning appears. My real question is why ostream and ofstream are treated differently.

```
struct Test {
    int y;
    Test(int k) : y(k) {}
};
```

With this simple struct, the compiler sees that an `int` can be converted to a `Test`.

Therefore, I get a warning with this code:

```
std :: ofstream& operator<<  (std :: ofstream& os, const Test& t)
{
    os << t.y;
    return os;
}
```

When it sees `os << t.y` it doesn't know whether I want to push the int called t.y, or whether I want to convert the int to a Test first and then push it. This seems pretty weird, you'd think it'd prefer the non-converted int overload `ofstream& operator<< (ofstream &os, int)`.

g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3:

```
template_expl.cpp: In function ‘std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream&, const Test&)’:
template_expl.cpp:15: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ostream.tcc:105: note: candidate 1: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
template_expl.cpp:13: note: candidate 2: std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream&, const Test&)
```

Anyway, one way to resolve this is to mark the constructor in Test as `explicit`. I can live with that. But the weird thing is that if `ofstream` is replaced with `ostream`, then the warning goes away. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the warning tells you, with `ofstream` both interpretations require conversions:

1. `ofstream& -> ostream&` in `static_cast<ostream&>(os) << t.y`,
2. `int -> Test` in `os << static_cast<Test>(t.y)`

If you use `ostream&` directly, then the `int`-interpretation requires *no* conversion and hence is preferred.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. But given that ofstream inherits from ostream, you would think that such a conversion would be a lot more natural. ofstream inherits `operator << (int)` from ostream. I would have thought that such a cast would be very much preferred by the standard.

Answer (score 7):

When you call

```
os << t.y;
```

you have 2 candidates:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream&, int) //1
```

and

```
ofstream& operator << (ofstream&, Test) //2
```

There is no such candidate as

```
ofstream& operator << (ofstream&, int) //3
```

According to the overload resolution rules, neither 1 nor 2 is better for your call. Hence the warning. In case of `ostream`, 1 is obviously a better match, because both arguments match exactly.

The best solution is to go with `std::ostream`. Why would you need to overload specifically for file streams. What if you need to stream it into a string? Overload output stream operator for `std::ostream` (or even a templatized version of `std::basic_ostream`) and let the compiler handle the rest.

Comment: It took me about 10 seconds to spot the difference (`*o*stream` vs `*of*stream`) between example 1 and 3...